# What defines pam password hashing?

Tags: rhel, password, pam, ldap

I have been running into an issue with pam password hashing. It seems no matter what I do on my RHEL based systems they always hash passwords based on MD5.

My goal here is to have ldap users who use the `passwd(1)` command have their password change on the remote ldap server. Currently this works fine but we need the hashing to stop so the ldap server can enforce a password policy. If we use an `ldapmodify` everything works fine and as expected. It's just when we use `passwd(1)` that it is always hashed with MD5.

We do want passwords in the shadow file to continue to be hashed. But not those who go through `pam_ldap.so`.

We have tried the following:

- adapting or removing the configuration found in `/etc/login.defs`.
- In the `/etc/pam_ldap.conf` or `/etc/ldap.conf` we made `pam_password` set to `clear` instead of `md5`.
- `/etc/pam.d/passwd` directs us to `system-auth`. We have tried removing the `md5` hash on the `pam_unix.so` line. The `pam_ldap.so` sits below it in the password section.
- using `authconfig --update --disablemd5`

I have made small bits of headway but even using `authconfig` and changing the hash to sha512 instead of md5 doesn't work. The format of the hash changes but when encode it in base64 it's MD5 again.